# Event system in pharo

Tags: events, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to make a simple user interface in Pharo 3.0. At a certain place I need a color picker, so I thought about using `ColorSelectorDialogWindow`.

My problem is that I am not sure how to actually get a color out of it. I have seen that it has a `selectedColor` message, but I miss a way to actually catch the event when the user clicks on the ok button.

I have tried `on: send: to:` but it does not seem to help and in any case I don't know the event name. I have also seen that on confirmation, the message `applyChanges` gets sent to self, so I tried subclassing `ColorSelectorDialogWindow` just to add

```
applyChanges
    super applyChanges.
    self triggerEvent: 'selectedColor' with: self selectedColor.
```

but it seems that I cannot catch my own `selectedColor` event using `on: send: to:`.

What is the right way to hook into the dialog ok, and more generally to send events between components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *Announcements*, a currently not very well documented part of Pharo.
Try this in a workspace:

```
| colorPicker |
colorPicker := ColorSelectorDialogWindow new.
colorPicker announcer when: ColorChanged do: [ :announcement | UIManager inform: 'Selected color: ' , announcement newColor asString ].
colorPicker open.
```

This is the example that can be found in the `ColorChanged` announcement class comment.
You get the selected color by sending `newColor` to the `ColorChanged` announcement.

Comment: Thank you, this works mostly fine. Still, it catches the moment the color is selected, not when it is confirmed. Any chance to react to the user clicking ok?

Comment: It seems I can watch the `WindowClosed` announcement, and then check whether `announcement window canceled` is true or false. Is there anything more direct?

Comment: See my second answer for an approach without announcements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open the `ColorSelectorDialogWindow` modally. In this case the `openModal` method only returns after the dialog was closed and you can get the selected color from the dialog directly:

```
| colorPicker |
colorPicker := ColorSelectorDialogWindow new.
colorPicker openModal.
colorPicker cancelled
    ifFalse: [UIManager inform: colorPicker selectedColor asString]
```

You probably do not want to make it modal like in my example, but modal to a specific other window. In this case use `anyWindow openModal: colorPicker`.